# pointers, conversion of char ** to char *

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I am studying pointers, but I have been stumped by the example program below. It is supposed to be doing a conversion of `char**` to `char*`, but I don't understand the logic behind the program. What is the program doing?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char *notes[] = {"cpp","python","java","mariadb"};
    void * base = notes; // notes and base, holds the address of note's first element
    void * elemAddr = (char*) base + 3* sizeof(char *); // i didn't understand this line???
    cout << *(char **)elemAddr;   // and this line

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's some pretty obfuscated code. I don't blame you for being confused.  Particularly casting `char * *` to `void *`.

Comment: I don't really see the point of this example. Trying to teach a concept by obfuscation seems like a poor strategy.

Comment: Where exactly is that conversion of char** to char* you are talking about?

Comment: @RawN `char *notes[]` decays to `char**`, cast to `void *base`, cast to `(char*)`.

Comment: @DrewDormann Right you are. Hard to go through that code.

Comment: this code is pure evil, waiting in the shadows to bite you. Hint: the line `(char*)base + 3 * sizeof(char*)` can also be written like `(char**) base + 3` (the latter makes a bit more sense). The former, however, treats `base` as a pointer-to-char (it just holds an address), so it needs to add `3 * sizeof(char*)` instead of just adding 3 to get the address of the last C-style string in the array

Comment: It might help if you draw a memory diagram. Keep track of where things point and remember that the number of bytes pointer addition advances by depends on the type of the pointer.

Comment: void pointer "base" holds the adress fo pointer of type char **. Below this line, in the line i commented as " (char*) base // i didn't understand this line??? ", i thought that this conversion occurs. Because, void pointer is converted to char*, since this void pointer holds the address of a char**, then i thought that this conversion is actually from char** to  char *

Comment: @metis, Once you have a `void*`, the initial type is lost unless you have it elsewhere. This is a form of type-erasure. The conversion at that point is from `void*` to `char*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'll bite:

```
char *notes[] = {"cpp","python","java","mariadb"};
```

Declares an array of pointers to `char *`. (should actually be `const char *notes[]` since we can't modify the content ever)

```
void * base = notes; // notes and base, holds the address of note's first element
```

So assigns the address of the array `notes` to `base`, and losing any type information in the process.

```
void * elemAddr = (char*) base + 3* sizeof(char *); // i didn't understand this line???
```

Cast `base` to `char *`, meaning each element is now `sizeof(char) == 1`. Add `3 * sizeof(char *)` to that pointer -> 3 elements into the `notes` array, and assign it back to `elemAddr`.

```
cout << *(char **)elemAddr;   // and this line
```

Since `elemAddr` is pointing to an element in `notes`, which is a `char*`, it really is a pointer to a pointer to `char`, and we want to print what it point to, hence the `*` at the very beginning.

It is not very readable, and it would be MUCH simpler to write

```
const char* notes[] =  { ... };
cout << notes[3];
```

but then you wouldn't have posted here...

Answer (score 5):

These lines:

```
char *notes[] = {"cpp","python","java","mariadb"};
void * base = notes; 
void * elemAddr = (char*) base + 3* sizeof(char *);
cout << *(char **)elemAddr;
```

are an obfuscated equivalent of:

```
char *notes[] = {"cpp","python","java","mariadb"};
cout << notes[3];
```

**Explanation:**

```
void * base = notes; 
void * elemAddr = (char*) base + 3* sizeof(char *);
```

is the same as:

```
char * base = (char*)notes; 
char * elemAddr = base + 3 * sizeof(char *);
```

Since pointers are usually of the same size, those lines are kind of the same as:

```
char ** base = notes; 
char ** elemAddr = base + 3;
```

which makes `elemAddr == &notes[3]`. That leads to the line

```
cout << *(char **)elemAddr;
```

to be the same as

```
cout << notes[3];
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the example code is meant to illustrate what goes on under the hood when you use array indexing.

Repeating the code (as it was when I wrote this):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char *notes[] = {"cpp","python","java","mariadb"};
    void * base = notes; // notes and base, holds the address of note's first element
    void * elemAddr = (char*) base + 3* sizeof(char *); // i didn't understand this line???
    cout << *(char **)elemAddr;   // and this line

    return 0;
}
```

First, the declaration

```
char *notes[] = {"cpp","python","java","mariadb"};
```

declares an array of pointers to `char`. Each pointer is initialized with a string literal. This language feature was deprecated in the original C++ standard, C++98, and was finally removed in C++11, so that with modern C++ (as of this writing C++14) it's just **invalid** code, code that will not compile with a conforming compiler.

In standard C++ it could be

```
char const *notes[] = {"cpp","python","java","mariadb"};
```

But let's ignore the `const` issue, and assume C++03 or C++98.

Then the declaration

```
void * base = notes;
```

declares a `void*` pointer called `base`, initialized to the address of the first item of the array `notes`. This works via array expression **decay**, where an expression referring to an array produces a pointer to its first item.

The declaration

```
void * elemAddr = (char*) base + 3* sizeof(char *);
```

is evidently intended to illustrate what's going on behind the scenes for the `[3]` indexing in

```
auto p = & notes[3];
```

This works via byte oriented address arithmetic (`char` and its variants is the C++ notion of smallest addressable unit, a.k.a. byte). Starting with the base address of the array, one adds 3 times the size of each item. This lands you on the start of the 3'rd item.

Finally, the expression

```
*(char **)elemAddr
```

uses that item. It's just ugly due to using low level types. But essentially, the item is a `char*` and so the address of the item is casted to `char**`, and then that pointer is dereferenced, yielding the `char*` pointer itself, which is the result of the expression (and passed to `cout`).

Answer (score 0):

The third line says:
"Convert base to a char pointer, and add 3 times the size of an char pointer to the result. Then, implicitly cast the result to a void pointer and store it in elemAddr"

In the end, elemAddr points to the address of "mariadb". The cast to (char*) isn't necessary to do the pointer arithmetic, but it prevents the compiler from printing a warning. It is equivalent to

```
&notes[3]
```

The fourth line tells the compiler to interpret the pointer as an pointer to char pointers. This pointer is then dereferenced so that the data pointed to by elemAddr is treated as an char pointer, which will be interpreted by std::cout as a C-string.

I don't know where you got this example from, but this type of programming is a honey pot for really horrible bugs and hard to debug code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go line by line:
1st Line: We create a pointer to an array of strings... this is a pointer to the base address of an array... of pointers.

2nd line: We make our char* into a void*, this this doesn't change the value of the pointer at all, just the type associated with it by the compiler.

3rd line: When we operate on the base pointer, we cast it to a char* essentially undoing what we did on line 2.  We add 3 * the sizeof( char*) to our pointer.  This makes the pointer that was pointing to the base of our array of pointers, now point to the 4th pointer in our array.

4th line: now we double deference our pointer, what is our pointer pointing to?  The third element in an array of pointers.  What is that pointer pointing to?  The string created back on line one.

Comment: The first line creates an array of pointers (meant to be interpreted as strings). There's no second level of pointer there.